# How many coaxial rotors could you theoretically stack on top of a helicopter before the design becomes infeasible?

Tags: rotorcraft

All coaxial-rotor helicopters in existence today have only 2 counter rotating rotor blades. An example of such a helicopter is the Kamov Ka-50. Coaxial-rotor helicopters have one big advantage compared to single-rotor helicopters and that is that they can lift a lot more.

My question is: Has anyone ever tried putting 4 counter-rotating rotors on a helicopter in order to increase its lift capacity even more? Would placing 4 or more stacked rotors on top of a helicopter be feasible?

Comment: "*they can lift a lot more*": The Mi-26 with a MTOW of 56 tons can lift a 20-ton workload with a single rotor, and many [heavy lift helicopters](https://aerocorner.com/blog/heavy-lift-helicopters/) don't have coaxial rotors, Kamov seems to be the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coaxial rotors don't have an advantage in lifting power because they have more rotors. The main advantage in that respect is that they don't need a tail rotor to maintain yaw control, meaning all the engine power can drive the main rotors.

Putting two rotors on the same axis increases the complexity quite a bit, but lets you remove the tail rotor. Putting four rotors on the same axis increases the complexity a lot more, for basically no extra benefit.

But it has been tried. Kind of. If you count [a rotor made of biplane wings as two rotors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pescara_Model_3_Helicopter), anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Coaxial-rotor helicopters have one big advantage compared to single-rotor helicopters and that is that they can lift a lot more

Coaxial rotor helicopter do not lift more than conventional helicopters: the same 7,700 kg (16,976 lb) of the Kamov Ka-50 can be easily lifted by the single rotor of the [H175](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Helicopters_H175) for example.

And as normally wrongly thought, coaxial helicopters do not even have the advantage that, missing the tail rotor, all the engine power goes in the main rotors: aerodynamic interferences between the two rotors make the lower one loose some 10 to 15% efficiency; and since in a conventional helicopter the tail rotor eats some 10 to 15% of the power available, let's just call it even.

---

Coaxial helicopters have only one advantage in respect to conventional helicopters: compactness.

Indeed, stacking two rotor one above the other, means that:

- the tail rotor with its tailboom is no more required and;
- the rotor diameter can be reduced, being the  thrust the same.

Being more compact a higher manoeuvrability can be expected which is for sure important for military helicopters.

Anyway this brings some disadvantages:

1. a horizontal tailplane (and the relevant tailboom) is still needed for stability, so you don't really get rid of the whole tailboom;
2. diameter of the rotor cannot be reduced too much before running into performance degradations;
3. as said, aerodynamic interferences between the rotors make the lower rotor loose some 10 to 15% efficiency;
4. rotor head becomes packed with rods and other rotating mechanisms increasing (a lot) the total aerodynamic drag and mechanical complexity ([picture source](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gV7_Xt-Wwso/WEwyybNKUwI/AAAAAAAAzJY/fnPTwX2FDAUPzi5gPv91wnhjWhMe56wAgCLcB/s1600/PCGh9.jpg));
   [image]
5. so many exposed mechanical part might fail and are for sure a target in military operations;
6. the second rotor atop shifts the CG upward which might reduce stability.
7. and for sure I'm forgetting something.

---

For all these reasons a coaxial design is really important where compactness is at a premium. Packing more rotors one on top of the other will only worsen everything, especially points 3., 4. and 5., without bringing any improvement.

Comment: That's not the only advantage. Maneuverability characteristics are significantly different, and mostly better (but there are some areas where a coaxial is also restricted).

Comment: @Therac: well yes, compactness reflect also in manoeuvrability, I'll update my answer